# Shell Script : How to copy list of files from Server 1 to Server 2

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scp

I need to copy list of files from Server 1 to Server 2.

I have a variable that he contains a list of selected files in Server 1.

```
echo "$linesBIV_SIP"

/var/opt/data/flat/88antr/files/CTLRealFSPT/done/PCSCF4C_client_list_20-09-2017-10-00.csv
/var/opt/data/flat/88antr/files/CTLRealFSPT/done/PCSCF5C_client_list_20-09-2017-15-18.csv
```

I want to copy these selected csv file to Server 2 :

I try :

```
scp "$linesBIV_SIP" root@hot0017:/opt/application/88antr/test_sh/
```

I have this error :

```
/var/opt/data/flat/88antr/files/CTLRealFSPT/done/PCSCF4C_client_list_20-09-2017-10-00.csv
/var/opt/data/flat/88antr/files/CTLRealFSPT/done/PCSCF5C_client_list_20-09-2017-15-18.csv: No such file or directory
```

I like to try to copy these file in sample command without bash script. Is it possible please ?

Please help. Thank you

Comment: FWIW, the error occurs because your variable `linesBIV_SIP` is interpreted as *one* file name, including a newline. Which is not illegal as far as the filesystem is concerned, just... ill advised. @Pavel's solution would have interpreted the newline as indicating a new file name, which -- *strictly* speaking -- would be wrong (as filenames are *allowed* to have newlines in them), and is a frequent mistake made when iterating over filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it :
I did like this and it's work fine :

```
scp "/var/opt/data/flat/88antr/files/CTLRealFSPT/done/PCSCF4C_client_list_20-09-2017-10-00.csv" "/var/opt/data/flat/88antr/files/CTLRealFSPT/done/PCSCF5C_client_list_20-09-2017-15-18.csv" root@hot0017:/opt/application/88antr/test_sh/
```

Thanks for all

Comment: Consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list via

```
for f in $linesBIV_SIP; do
  scp $f root@hot0017:/opt/application/88antr/test_sh/
done
```

And upload files one by one. You can execute that as a one-liner in a terminal, if you need.